# SQL Order by DESC on alphanumeric field with numbers before words

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, kentico

I have a column in a SQL table I'm trying to do an order by on. The data needs to be in desc so it shows more recent years first.

```
Sample Data         Expect Output
-----------         -------------
older                   2013
2012                    2012
2013                    2011
2011                    older
```

Using this particular method I only have access to the `Order by` and `WHERE` clauses rather than full blown SQL.

This limits me from being able to pull the data out in 2 sets and joining.
I also can not manipulate the `older` field to something like `999order` and strip the `999` out later.

Is there a way to order by that will give me what I'm looking for?

Comment: What is the 'particular method' are you talking about? Did you try using dataquery? http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/kentico-8-technology-dataquery-advanced-api (it supports joins)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
WITH tbl AS(
    SELECT 'older' AS date_col UNION ALL
    SELECT '2012' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2011'
)
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN date_col NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END,
    date_col DESC
```

`NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` means that the `date_col` is composed of all numbers. Assign `0` to these rows since they will be first in the sorting. Then sort by `date_col DESC`.

**RESULT**

```
date_col
--------
2013
2012
2011
older
```

Answer (score 0):

One (dirty) trick is to use the [`bin`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_bin) function: it will return `'0'` for a non-numeric string, so `'older`' will come first:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
ORDER BY BIN(year_column)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

`SELECT * FROM t5 ORDER BY BIN(samp_data) DESC;`

Answer (score 0):

Can we not use the `ISNUMERIC()` function instead of `NOT LIKE`

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
(
value varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO @test
VALUES
('2010'),
('2011'),
('2012'),
('2013'),
('2014'),
('2015'),
('older')

SELECT * From @test
ORDER BY 
    (CASE  WHEN ISNUMERIC(value) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),value DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show numeric rows first

```
Select * 
From  [Table Name] 
Order By IsNumeric([Column Name]) DESC, [Column Name] DESC
```